# Flyway - specify configuration on command line for maven?

Tags: maven, jdbc, flyway

I'm running this command:

```
mvn install flyway:migrate -DskipTests=true -Dflyway.configFile=C:\\itconfig.properties
```

I need an external configuration for my migrations in certain circumstances. However, whenever I run this, my flyway properties in my pom file take precedence. The documentation state:

> Overriding order
>
> System properties override External config file overrides Maven
>   properties override Plugin configuration

But its not working that way for me. Am I doing anything wrong? I did find this previous issue, but it appears closed / fixed?:

https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/585

Answer (score 0):

Please file an issue in the Flyway issue tracker.